# Populate Class Properties via 1 line within a for loop?

Tags: ios, swift2

Let's say I have a class that has 10 properties.  I have an XML response (AEXMLDocument in this case) where the element tags match the property names exactly.  Is there a way I could populate the values in a for loop rather than writing out 10 lines of code?  I used ***property.name**** to show where I would like to put these variables.  That part is not actually in the code.

```
class User(){
   var firstName = String()
   var lastName = String()
   var middleName = String()
   ...
   var property10 = String()

}

func populateUser (xml: AEXMLDocument) -> User{
    var returnUser = User()
    for property in xml.root["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["ns1:getUserResponse"]["return"].children{
        returnUser.***property.name*** = property.value
}
return returnUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setValue(_, forKey:)` method as long as you subclass from NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

If the class inherits from NSObject, you can use [key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html):

```
returnUser.setValue(property.value, forKey: property.name)
```

Be careful with this though.  Anyone who can modify the XML sent to your app can modify any property on the User object.